# how to use click function after checking the div inline property

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use click function if the div inline property is 'block'

```
if ($('.click-to-exit').css('display') == 'block'){
$(document).click( function() {
    alert('OK');
});}
```

but its not working.
am I doing some thing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way around:

```
$(document).click( function() {
    if ($('.click-to-exit').css('display') == 'block'){
       alert('OK');
    }
});
```

Also, if you haven't already, use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

So

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click( function() {
        if ($('.click-to-exit').css('display') == 'block'){
           alert('OK');
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: I tried the click first and its working , but I want to check if the div is block then action trigger otherwise not action

Comment: unrelated : do we have private message over here, so I can show you what the actual problem is if I used first click event

Comment: I don't think so, can't you just post it here?

Comment: http://www.pegahghaemi.com/

just want if click any where, video muted. and only play when click on play button
If i use click event first then check the condition, its works , but when you click on play button again, it trigger this function again

Comment: You could just have a variable muted or something. `Clicked? > If display = block AND muted = 0 > Trigger function`? Or do you want them to be abled to unmute it aswell?

Comment: @L Ja now check, 
the condition checked after click. so once you video mute, cant turn it on.